# How do I control the appearance of a Locator inside a Mathematica's Manipulate statement?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

If I have a Manipulate statement, such as:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, pt}], PlotRange -> 2], {{pt, {1, 1}}, 
  Locator}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How do I change the appearance of the Locator object in the easiest way possible? Do I have to resort to Dynamic statements? Specifically, I would have liked to make the Locator invisible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In addition to [WReach's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316493/how-do-i-control-the-appearance-of-a-locator-inside-a-mathematicas-manipulate-st/5316694#5316694): In a normal `Locator` call its appearance can be given as one of the arguments. When used in a `Manipulate` this is not possible. However, `Appearance` can be used to draw other locator symbols.

```
a = Graphics[{Red, Table[Circle[{0, 0}, i], {i, 3}]}, ImageSize -> 20];
Manipulate[
 Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, pt}], PlotRange -> 2], {{pt, {1, 1}}, Locator,
   Appearance -> a}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I don't think this is documented. Last year I tried finding out how to do this, but couldn't find a way. Got no response on my [question](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/2a8fc512cc9cb0bc) on the mathematica newsgroup either.

Comment: The Mathematica documentation on this point is sparse (understatement).  Prior to V8, the documentation simply showed an example with the explanation "control with particular options".  In V8, they added the explicit sentence "Options for the controls can also be given within the specification for the variables".  This is an example of something that has happened to me a few times: an unreasonably close reading of the documentation uncovers a significant feature.

Comment: @WReach Yeah, I second that. The Appearance doc page doesn't even allude to the possibility that it could be used to point to visual objects, such as graphics or text. It seems to indicate that you can only change the size of the locator. Again, you encounter the phrase "Typical settings for Appearance include..." a phrase that occurs annoyingly often in the docs.

Comment: +1 Thanks for this. Previously I have drawn arbitrary locator symbols by using `Appearance->None` then drawing the symbol ontop of the locator (eg [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ScalarFeynmanDiagramsAndSymanzikPolynomials/) where I used the graph's vertex rendering function). Now I can use something like `Appearance -> Dynamic[Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[pt]}]]`.

Comment: @Simon You're welcome. Actually, the OP and WReach were pivotal in this find. I'm pretty new to StackOverflow, but I really like the interactivity it offers. Makes things like this happen.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding `Appearance -> None` to the Locator control:

```
Manipulate[
  Graphics[
    Line[{{0, 0}, pt}]
  , PlotRange -> 2
  ]
, {{pt, {1, 1}}, Locator, Appearance -> None}
]
```